# How to set appearance preferences visual effect to "extra"?

Tags: 10.10

I have installed ubuntu 10.10 on my dell inspiron 15r queen 3gb ram and i5 processor and unable to set the appearance preferences visual effects to EXTRA mode.

Tell me how can I do that?

Comment: What video card do you have? Is it Intel? what Intel card?, is it Nvidia o Ati?

Comment: Hello, this question has no information and activity for a very long time. I am voting to close it for now. If by any reason you think this question is still viable or useful in anyways or that there is still a good chance it will be answered please flag it to a moderator or add a comment with the reasons why you want it open. Regards.